# Failed TCP accept: emfile

Tags: ejabberd, tsung

I got this error after reaching  Current request rate:    11.12 req/sec
 Current users:           1184
 Current connected users: 990 
 Current phase:           1
ejabberd tsung testing  after that i google it some of them suggested to increase the  /proc/sys/fs/file-max
ulimit -n 100000 there after also i space the same problem is there any solution for this.

Comment: Is the error emfile is raised by tsung or by ejabberd ?

Comment: this emfile error occur in ejabberd log file only not for tsung

Answer (score 3):

Just for an answer.

This is an issue with file descriptors limit of your OS. ejabberd opens new port for each new connection and this new port happens to use file descriptors. By default file descriptor limit is 1024 (Check with ulimit -n). Increase this limit to 30000 (with ulimit -n 30000)

Check this link for more details - [File Descriptors are Yummy or Common Pitfalls of Ejabberd](http://metajack.im/2008/09/23/file-descriptors-are-yummy-or-common-pitfalls-of-ejabberd/)

Comment: I think you mean ulimit, not uname.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that your stress load is too high, reduce the number of users or deploy more than one ejebberd. You could give us more information on your test too to help us helping you.